# Why are functions called "callback" in JavaScript when nothing is calling them back?

Tags: javascript

In C# a call back is called after an asynchronous call is made. It means "when the async work is done, call back to this function."

Yet, I often hear this construct in JavaScript:

```
describe(player, function() {...
});
```

called a call-back.  In what way is it a callback?

Comment: Things are calling them - most often the function that you pass them into calls them.

Comment: In what way is it *not* a callback?!

Comment: in your example, only the function() {} is the callback. A reasonable example would be: loadUser(userId, function(user) { var name = user.lastName; })

Comment: functions is a functions, it calls callback when you set it as function param and then run it inside

Comment: -1 Why does it matter? How is C# relevant to terminology used by JavaScript developers?

Comment: To build upon @deceze's comment, it's difficult to answer your question when you don't specify why you think such a use might *not* be a callback. It seems obvious to me that such a use is a callback, but it's not obvious to you. Without more clarification about your confusion, I can only answer, "It's a callback by definition," which doesn't seem likely to help you. Perhaps you could give a C# sample that exemplifies your current understanding of callbacks, and then explain how the JS example is different to you.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want. JavaScript developers call it a callback. What law is there that governs all languages and all the  terminology used by their respective developers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a function that you pass into another function that will **call** that function **back** when a certain thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

It is called *callback* because as you call function X (`describe` in your case), the function X will call "you" back using the *callback* (= will call the callback function).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript a callback function is just a reference to an executable code, or a piece of executable code, that is passed as an argument to other code. It doesn't matter when it will be *called back* - maybe immediately.